# Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

Here's my generic problem:

My project P depends on A which depends on B which depends on C which depends on version 1.0.1 of D.

There's a problem with version 1.0.1 of D and I want to force the use of another module. I don't know how to declare this in my project's POMs since I haven't added a dependency on D directly. It's C which declared the dependency on D.

Important: In this case, not only the version is changed, but the group & artifact as well. So it's not just a matter of overriding the version of the dependency, but rather, of excluding a module and including another one.

In the concrete case, D is StAX whose 1.0.1 has a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6402423). According to the notes in the bug, "the problems were solved by replacing the stax-api-1.0.1 (maven GroupId = stax) by stax-api-1.0-2 (maven GroupId = javax.xml.stream)" so I'm trying just that.

Thus, D = stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1 and C = org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0

I'm using maven 2.0.9 in case it matters.

Output of mvn dependency:tree"

```
mvn dependency:tree
[..snip..]
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

In my project's POM I have the following dependency on "A":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Simply specify the version in your current pom. The version specified here will override other.

> **Forcing a version**
>   A version will always be honoured if it is declared in the current POM with a particular version - however, it should be noted that this will also affect other poms downstream if it is itself depended on using transitive dependencies.

---

**Resources :**

- [Dependency Mediation and Conflict Resolution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution)
- [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: it's not clear how I can specify the version since I don't declare a dependency on D. Also, the first link you provided has "This document describes the rest of the requirements for dependency management that have NOT yet been implemented for Maven 2.0, especially with regards to transitive dependencies." at the top.

Comment: @wishihadabettername, As said in the other document : "You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0"

Comment: You actually duplicate the very same <dependency> entry in your own pom. In your dependency, specify a <version> that you want. That will override any version used by "deeper" dependencies.

Comment: Don't add direct dependencies to things that don't actually use them directly.  Use `<dependencyManagement>` instead, as per [Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44020271/507761).

Answer (score 36):

Alternatively, you can just exclude the dependency that you don't want. STAX is included in JDK 1.6, so if you're using 1.6 you can just exclude it entirely.

My example below is slightly wrong for you - you only need one of the two exclusions but I'm not quite sure which one. There are other versions of Stax floating about, in my example below I was importing A which imported B which imported C & D which each (through yet more transitive dependencies) imported different versions of Stax. So in my dependency on 'A', I excluded both versions of Stax.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>a.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>a.artifact</artifactId>
  <version>a.version</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!--  STAX comes with Java 1.6 -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>stax</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
<dependency>
```

Comment: It is necessary to note that this transitive dependency can be used and exclusion can cause a build failure if it is in need.

Comment: If you are using a modern JDK (i.e. 1.6+) and you need the much older version of stax included via a transitive dependency, you are probably going to run into all sorts of terrible runtime class loader issues. My advice: use the one in the JDK. If you get a "build failure" you are relying on an ancient API of some form that should be upgraded. Or: roll back your JDK to 1.5. Good Luck with that.

Answer (score 31):

What you put inside the `</dependencies>` tag of the root pom will be included by all child modules of the root pom. If all your modules use that dependency, this is the way to go.

However, if only 3 out of 10 of your child modules use some dependency, you do not want this dependency to be included in all your child modules. In that case, you can just put the dependency inside the `</dependencyManagement>`. This will make sure that any child module that needs the dependency must declare it in their own pom file, but they will use the same version of that dependency as specified in your `</dependencyManagement>` tag.

You can also use the `</dependencyManagement>` to modify the version used in transitive dependencies, because the version declared in the upper most pom file is the one that will be used. This can be useful if your project A includes an external project B v1.0 that includes another external project C v1.0. Sometimes it happens that a security breach is found in project C v1.0 which is corrected in v1.1, but the developers of B are slow to update their project to use v1.1 of C. In that case, you can simply declare a dependency on C v1.1 in your project's root pom inside `, and everything will be good (assuming that B v1.0 will still be able to compile with C v1.1).

Comment: using a Kotlin dependency with a Spring Boot parent, the dependencyManagement approach (at the top level) is the only solution that worked

Comment: This is the right answer. You don't want these libraries cluttering up your POM unless you know you will continue to have them as transtive dependencies forever.

Comment: Please read and understand this bug: "Dependency management is not transitive." https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5761 before trying this solution. It may not work for your problem.

Answer (score 25):

I also had trouble overruling a dependency in a third party library. I used [scot's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9169808/304270) with the exclusion but I also added the dependency with the newer version in the pom. (I used Maven 3.3.3)

So for the stAX example it would look like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>a.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>a.artifact</artifactId>
  <version>a.version</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!--  STAX comes with Java 1.6 -->
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>stax</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
<dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is correct but I'd like to add my two cents. I've run into a problem where I had a project A that had a project B as a dependency. Both projects use slf4j but project B uses log4j while project A uses logback.
Project B uses slf4j 1.6.1, while project A uses slf4j 1.7.5 (due to the already included logback 1.2.3 dependency).

**The problem:** Project A couldn't find a function that exists on slf4j 1.7.5, after checking eclipe's dependency hierarchy tab I found out that during build it was using slf4j 1.6.1 from project B, instead of using logback's slf4j 1.7.5.

I solved the issue by changing the order of the dependencies on project A pom, when I moved project B entry below the logback entry then maven started to build the project using slf4j 1.7.5.

**Edit:**
Adding the slf4j 1.7.5 dependency before Project B dependency worked too.

Comment: You should use the Enforcer plugin to require dependency convergence, so that your projects aren't pulling in random versions of things depending on which one they encounter first.  Such a conflict should cause a build error until you explicitly pick a version.  https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html