# Doxygen Failing with another ant task

Tags: java, maven, ant, groovy, doxygen

So doxygen is running in my maven project as an ant task. I'm trying to add codenarc (groovy style checker) to my project, also using an ant task.

Once they're both there, I start getting an error when I do a build. (This doesn't happen when only the doxygen task is there).

It looks like for some reason when I add the CodeNarc ant task, it stops being able to find the doxygen executable it needs to run.

Here's the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run 
(doxygen-generate) on project myproject: An Ant BuildException has occured: 
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "doxygen" 
(in directory "/Users/user/Developer/root/project/myproject"): error=2, 
No such file or directory

[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="/Users/user/Developer/root/project/myproject" 
executable="doxygen">... @ 5:95 
in /Users/user/Developer/root/project/myproject/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I need them to play nice together.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be due to **CodeNarc**'s explicit dependency on Ant or some other dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If so, perhaps you could exclude that, e.g.
[Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. I'm running CodeNarc in an ant task, so the ant task is depending on CodeNarc rather than the other way around.