# After adding maven dependencies for GWT-Maps-V3-Api I can not compile app

Tags: maven, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I need help with GWT 2.7 and google maps.

I have spring/gwt project which successfully builds with maven.

Now I would like to use this library:
[GWT-Maps-V3-Api](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api)

So I've added to my pom.xml file:

```
<!-- GWT Maps API V3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.branflake2267</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maps-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0-alpha-7</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when I am trying to compile project I am getting an error:

here is `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RestGWT 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to /home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target/restgwt/WEB-INF/classes
[WARNING] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
[INFO] Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.0.2.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [com.sagar.restgwt.restgwt]
[ERROR] Unknown argument: -XfragmentCount
[ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.0.3
[ERROR] Compiler [-logLevel level] [-workDir dir] [-gen dir] [-style style] [-ea] [-XdisableClassMetadata] [-XdisableCastChecking] [-validateOnly] [-draftCompile] [-compileReport] [-localWorkers count] [-war dir] [-extra dir] module[s] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] where 
[ERROR]   -logLevel               The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
[ERROR]   -workDir                The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
[ERROR]   -gen                    Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
[ERROR]   -style                  Script output style: OBF[USCATED], PRETTY, or DETAILED (defaults to OBF)
[ERROR]   -ea                     Debugging: causes the compiled output to check assert statements
[ERROR]   -XdisableClassMetadata  EXPERIMENTAL: Disables some java.lang.Class methods (e.g. getName())
[ERROR]   -XdisableCastChecking   EXPERIMENTAL: Disables run-time checking of cast operations
[ERROR]   -validateOnly           Validate all source code, but do not compile
[ERROR]   -draftCompile           Enable faster, but less-optimized, compilations
[ERROR]   -compileReport          Create a compile report that tells the Story of Your Compile
[ERROR]   -localWorkers           The number of local workers to use when compiling permutations
[ERROR]   -war                    The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
[ERROR]   -extra                  The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
[ERROR] and 
[ERROR]   module[s]               Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.296 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-18T14:38:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/334M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project RestGWT: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512m' '-classpath' '/home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target/restgwt/WEB-INF/classes:/home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/src/main/java:/home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target/generated-sources/annotations:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material/1.4/gwt-material-1.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-themes/1.4/gwt-material-themes-1.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/restygwt/restygwt/2.0.3/restygwt-2.0.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.4.1/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.4.1/jackson-core-asl-1.4.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.3/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate4/2.6.3/jackson-datatype-hibernate4-2.6.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.3/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.7/aspectjrt-1.8.7.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.16/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/2.4.0-b09/javax.inject-2.4.0-b09.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.16/jersey-common-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.16/jersey-guava-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-server/2.16/jersey-server-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.16/jersey-client-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.16/jersey-media-jaxb-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.4.0-b09/hk2-api-2.4.0-b09.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b09/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b09.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.4.0-b09/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b09.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.4.0-b09/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b09.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-json-processing/2.16/jersey-media-json-processing-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jsonp-jaxrs/1.0/jsonp-jaxrs-1.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.16/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-entity-filtering/2.16/jersey-entity-filtering-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.3.2/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.3.2/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.3.2/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.16/jersey-container-servlet-2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/0.9.1/gwtbootstrap3-0.9.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-extras/0.9.1/gwtbootstrap3-extras-0.9.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.182/h2-1.4.182.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.7.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/persistence-api-1.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/5.0.2.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.0.2.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.2.Final/hibernate-validator-4.3.2.Final.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.5/joda-time-2.5.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jadira/usertype/usertype.extended/3.2.0.GA/usertype.extended-3.2.0.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jadira/usertype/usertype.spi/3.2.0.GA/usertype.spi-3.2.0.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/jadira/usertype/usertype.core/3.2.0.GA/usertype.core-3.2.0.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.0/commons-lang3-3.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/github/branflake2267/gwt-maps-api/3.10.0-alpha-7/gwt-maps-api-3.10.0-alpha-7.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader/1.1.0/gwt-ajaxloader-1.1.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.0.3/gwt-dev-2.0.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.7.0/gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.0.3/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:/home/korbeldaniel/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-style' 'OBF' '-war' '/home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target/restgwt' '-localWorkers' '8' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' 'auto' '-gen' '/home/korbeldaniel/git/restgwt/target/.generated' 'com.sagar.restgwt.restgwt'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sagar.restgwt</groupId>
<artifactId>RestGWT</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-material</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-material-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.restygwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>restygwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring ends -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- GWTBootstrap3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gwtbootstrap3</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtbootstrap3</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gwtbootstrap3</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtbootstrap3-extras</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- GWTBootstrap3 ends -->



    <!-- DB related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.182</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DB related dependencies ends -->

    <!-- JPA model generator dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JPA model generator dependencies ends -->

    <!-- Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Validation ends -->

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging ends -->

    <!-- Custom formats -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.extended</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Custom formats ends -->



    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tests ends -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

com.github.branflake2267
    gwt-maps-api
    3.10.0-alpha-7

```
</dependencies>


<properties>
    <basedir>.</basedir>
    <gwt.version>2.7.0</gwt.version>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.9.1.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.36</mysql.connector.version>


    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}\${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
</properties>




<build>
    <finalName>restgwt</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <!-- <goal>i18n</goal> <goal>generateAsync</goal> -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>RestGWT.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>${gwt.version}</version> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>compile</goal> 
            <goal>test</goal> <goal>generateAsync</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> 
            <configuration> <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp> </configuration> 
            </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact that gwt-maps-api v3.10.0-alpha-7 has a transient dependency on gwt-dev v2.0.3 and the gwt-maven-plugin v2.7.0 is trying to pass a command line parameter to named -XfragmentCount to the com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.

The compiler does not recognize this option because it was added to gwt-dev subsequent to v2.0.3 (I didn't have the time to find out exactly which version included this support).

You have two options:

1. Override the transient dependency on v2.0.3 of the gwt-dev package by explicitly adding a dependency to a later version in your POM.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
>   <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
>   <version>2.7.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

See [Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library).

This might cause you problems though because it might break the GWT-Maps-V3-Api lib if the newer version of gwt-dev is not 100% backward compatible with v2.0.3.

2. Go back and use an older version of the gwt-maven-plugin which does not add the '-XfragmentCount' option to the compile.  Looking at the docs for the gwt:compile goal for the plugin it looks like the support for specifying the fragment count was added in v2.5.0 of the plugin.  You could change the version of the gwt-maven-plugin to something prior to 2.5.0 and give it a try.

> ```
>  <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>         <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.1.0 ??? OR SOMETHING ?? </version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>           ...
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
> ```

Comment: Hej. I've updated my post with pom.xml code. Please look at it.

Comment: Your problem still seems to be the 2.7.0 version of the gwt-maven-plugin isn't compat with the 2.0.3 gwt.  `[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ RestGWT ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [com.sagar.restgwt.restgwt]
[ERROR] Unknown argument: -XfragmentCount
[ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.0.3`.  Intstead of using gwt.version as the version for the plugin what if you go back to something prior to 2.5.0?

Comment: I've tried both solutions. The first one worked out for me. I've Just added dependency to gwt-dev. Thanks.