# Incorrect javax.xml.stream:stax-api:POM version referenced from Spring files

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, spring-ws, stax

We have been using Spring 3.0 reference libraries in our project and recently while building our project, we came across incorrect stax-api pom version which it is trying to lookup and getting timeout error

```
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0.2/stax-api-1.0.2.pom
```

Upon our research we found that correct version is javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2  , but we are quite confused as we have used Spring libraries only .
We haven't mentioned anywhere in our application POM files. We are including dependency for spring-ws-core though but if internally it references wrong POM , how are we supposed to change it.

Comment: Why not using [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.xml.stream|stax-api|1.0-2|jar)

Comment: what version of spring-ws-core do you use?

Comment: The question is not about the repo its about the stax-api-1.0.2.pom which is wrongly mentioned in spring pom files ,  **it should  have been stax-api-1.0-2.pom instead of stax-api-1.0.2.pom**

Comment: spring-ws-core version is 1.5.9

Comment: on googling , i found a similar issue with stax api version..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library

Answer (score 1):

**spring-ws-core** artifact in maven central correctly references(depends) stax-api.jar from version above 1.5.7(spring-ws-core)

```
javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:xxxx
```

whereas version 1.5.6(spring-ws-core) depends on `stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile`

probably the repository that you may be referring to should contain bad referenced stax jar

you may want add central repository if you are using a repository manager

Comment: Maven Central is by default configured in Maven. If you are using a repository manager than you might need to configure it there correctly.

Comment: stax-api was hardcoded in the main POM by somebody :-( and it was referring to 1.0.2 which was wrong so removed the hardcoded dependencies and it picked the right version from repository where it was required dynamically