# ERROR JacksonVersion - Version '2.9.4' of package 'jackson-databind' is not supported

Tags: java, azure, maven, apache-kafka, jackson

i am using azure sdk(azure-storage-file-datalake, azure-core, azure-identity) for writing the avro data to azure datalake gen 2 from kafka(using connectors), but i am getting very weird errors as below

2022-05-12 10:46:10 ERROR JacksonVersion:506 - Version '2.9.4' of package 'jackson-annotations' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - 2.10.0), please upgrade.

2022-05-12 10:46:10 ERROR JacksonVersion:506 - Version '2.9.4' of package 'jackson-core' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - 2.10.0), please upgrade.

2022-05-12 10:46:10 ERROR JacksonVersion:506 - Version '2.9.4' of package 'jackson-databind' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - 2.10.0), please upgrade.

java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.9.4, jackson-core=2.9.4, jackson-databind=2.9.4, jackson-dataformat-xml=unknown, jackson-datatype-jsr310=unknown, azure-core=1.28.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: [https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot\n\tat](https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot%5Cn%5Ctat) com.azure.core.implementation

I have tried excluding the jackson dependencies and tried adding explicitly, still i am getting the errors.

please some one help on this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
    <dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache avro dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Newer versions of the storage account jar is not working. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
        <version>12.9.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Collision with Kafka Jackson dependencies -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.linguafranca.pwdb</groupId>
                <artifactId>KeePassJava2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version> <!-- {x-version-update;com.microsoft.azure:msal4j;external_dependency} -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Schema registry dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-avro-converter</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>






</dependencies>
```

Comment: Above dependencies i have added explicitly in pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting environment had those 2.9.4 versioned jackson jars which were loading at run time and causing the issues, i replaced those with newer version jars , its working all fine now.
(we had installed kafka client on the host, which internally had those jars inside kafka/libs)

got the ans from - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/28902

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies with scope "runtime" are not used for compilation, but only for execution. A dependency with this scope is not put on the compile classpath, so you could remove the runtime scope.

However a better way to overwrite transitive dependency versions that you don't use yourself is to use depependency management like this:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    [...]
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and response here.
 i tried like this by following https://www.baeldung.com/maven-version-collision
still the same error.

Comment: Error-
 java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.9.4, jackson-core=2.9.4, jackson-databind=2.9.4, jackson-dataformat-xml=unknown, jackson-datatype-jsr310=unknown, azure-core=1.28.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot\n\tat com.azure.core.implementation

Comment: Hm, I never had an unknown version, did you forget to specify the version for those dependencies in the dependency management section?

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge with Azure-SDK (here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/25734)). Azure-SDK has a dependency on Jackson. The specific version of Jackson depends on the azure-sdk version you are using.

The latest release [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/troubleshooting-dependency-version-conflict#support-for-multiple-jackson-versions) Jackson 2.10-2.13. What it means is you may have other dependencies on Jackson, and the SDK will still work. Provided Jackson version fetched is from 2.10-2.13. Azure-SDK is compatible with all these versions.

If you wish to use Jackson 2.9 (or if that's coming as a dependency from other dependency), then there is no way around it. **You would necessarily need to upgrade your dependencies so that it fetches jackson 2.10 and above**.

In your case, there would be some dependency that is fetching 2.9.x series.

This is what I would do:

1. Based on all non-azure-sdk dependencies. Decide which jackson version to hold on to. Explicitly add this jackson dependency in the pom.xml
2. Use azure-sdk [BOM](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/boms/azure-sdk-bom/README.md)
3. You dont have to specify exclusion. Specifying a version in pom [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library) other dependency versions

Comment: i have tried these all these steps, still the error is not going away, really this is some  ugly issue

Comment: There is some dependency that is fetching in jackson 2.9. Can you check dependencyGraph of your project?

Comment: ok, i will check

Comment: there is no transient dependency(jackson ones) in the dependency tree